# Automatically migrate an openstack instance on node failure

Tags: high-availability, failover, openstack

I'm wondering if there is an option on modern nova (Beyond newton) allowing me to automatically failover an instances that is hosted on a failed node?

I know that the purpose of the cloud is to create a swarm and so don't bother about this kind of issue, but, you know, clients don't always behave like you intend it will.

Additionally, I don't want to force my clients to spawn multiple instances and so paid twice the price just to be sure that nothing bad happen.

Is this achievable without using distributed/shared storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after digging a little bit, I find out that Openstack labeled this issue as a critical feature lack and is working on it as stated here:

[Openstack VM_HA](https://docs.openstack.org/ha-guide/compute-node-ha.html)

This purposal and discussion has been opened in 2016 and not yet implemented as for July 2017

Status of this issue can be followed here:

[VM_HA status](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/ProductTeam/User_Stories/HA_VMs)

As explain on both links, some workaround are available through vendor specific solution but not considered as natively implemented.